# Create 2 subdivs of child Div and add Dynamic unique ID on Appended Child Divs?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, blackjack

I am currently building a blackjack game and each time I press "hit", I run this function which appends divs that represents a card pulled from a deck.

I am able to set a ID to the div, but I want each ID to increment in value... So div1, div2, div3. Currently, each div gets the same ID, which would be useless when trying to add values to each card.

Another issue I am having is trying to add 2 more sub divs ( each with unique IDs ) to this new "card" div that I can fill with the "suit" and "value" of the card.

Here is my function so far...

```
function hitMe() {

var playerCards = document.getElementById("playerCards");
let newCard = document.createElement("div");
newCard.textContent = "Hello";
playerCards.appendChild(newCard);
newCard.setAttribute("id", "id_Here");

}
```

So Once i create each card, I want the "Hello" to be replaced with the cards value and the cards suit.

The card value and Card suit can be obtained using this deck / player creation method

```
var suits = ["&spades", "&hearts", "&diams", "&clubs"];
var values = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];

var deck = new Array();

function createDeck() {
deck = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < suits.length; x++) {
      var weight = parseInt(values[i]);
      if (values[i] == "J" || values[i] == "Q" || values[i] == "K") weight = 10;
      if (values[i] == "A") weight = 11;
      var card = { Value: values[i], Suit: suits[x], Weight: weight };
      deck.push(card);
    }
  }
}



var players = new Array();
function createPlayers(num) {
  players = new Array();
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    var hand = new Array();
    var player = { Name: "Player " + i, ID: i, Points: 0, Hand: hand };
    players.push(player);
  }
}

function deal() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
      var card = deck.pop();
      players[x].Hand.push(card);
      renderCard(card, x);
      updatePoints();
    }
  }
  updateDeck();
}
```

If anyone would have a more simplified solution for the code listed above and how to go about this I would be great-ful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id of the previous element in playerCards to define the current id.
For the unique ID for the suit and value you can then base yourself on the id of the card.

Here is an example:

```
function hitMe() {
  var playerCards = document.getElementById("playerCards")
  let newCard = document.createElement("div")
  newCard.innerText = "Hello"

  // Card ID
  let cardID
  if(playerCards.lastChild === null) { // create first id if no childs
    cardID = 'card1'
  } else {
    // take the id number of previous elem and increment by one
    let number = parseInt(playerCards.lastChild.id.substring(3,playerCards.lastChild.id.length))
    cardID = 'card' + (number + 1)
  }

  // suit and value id
  let valueDIV = document.createElement("div")
  let suitDIV = document.createElement("div")

  let valueID = cardID + '-value'
  let suitID = cardID + '-suit'

  // set some custom values
  valueDIV.innerText = "some number"
  suitDIV.innerText = "some suit"

  // set ids and append elems
  newCard.id = cardID
  valueDIV.id = valueID
  suitDIV.id = suitID

  newCard.appendChild(valueDIV)
  newCard.appendChild(suitDIV)
  playerCards.appendChild(newCard)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `createElement`, just use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var id = 0;

function hitMe(card) {
  var playerCards = document.getElementById("playerCards");
  playerCards.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
  `<div id='card${id}' class='card'>
     <div id='suit${id}' class='suit'>${card.Suit}</div>
     <div id='value${id}' class='value'>${card.Value}</div>
   </div>`);
  id++;
}
```